# Kindle Fire homescreen app. icon

Tags: android, icons, homescreen, kindle-fire

on my **Kindle Fire** home screen the icon of my application sometimes is shown as a plain gray square. Rebooting device returns normal application icon back. is it a known issue on Kindle fire?

Comment: By any chance is the app installed on the SD card / external storage?

Comment: it's on internal storage

Answer (score 3):

Kindle shows the image uploaded on amazon market to show on home screen, you can add a app as a favorite and it will show you the app icon mentioned in manifest, please make sure you have a high res image uploaded on amazon market as thumbnail. side loaded app cannot use this feature

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this is to put in 512x512 icon. I know it's not pretty, but it gets job done, as all Android devices resize icons to appropriate size.

If somebody has better solution that doesn't involve uploading app to Amazon Market - please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the MDPI, HDPI, and XHDPI icons all going? I think it might be showing a grey box because one of those isn't in there.

(If you submitted your app to the app store, it's the HDPI icon. If you didn't, it's the MDPI icon. Because of this, it might be getting confused as to which icon to get. Also, you can replace your MDPI icon with a 200x200 image to make it appear hi-res in the Kindle Fire.)

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add hdpi or xhdpi resources; the Kindle Fire is an mdpi device.

Comment: anyway it hasn't helped me. The icon is shown in carusel after installation of the app. But become as a gray square after sometime. icon.png size is 256x256

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is to use custom drawable folders for kindles

```
custom drawable "drawable-1024x600-v10" with ic_launcher.png for KindleFire 1 st Gen
custom drawable "drawable-1024x600-v15" with ic_launcher.png for KindleFire 2nd Gen
custom drawable "drawable-1280x800" with ic_launcher.png for  KindleFire HD-7'
custom drawable "drawable-1920x1200" with ic_launcher.png for  KindleFire HD-8.9'
```

Using these drawable folders will ensure that the kindle icons will look good. meanwhile use your standard Android icons in the standard drawable folders.

```
ldpi (120 dpi) (Low density screen)             36 x 36 px 
mdpi (160dpi)(Medium density screen)            48 x 48 px 
hdpi (240 dpi)(Highdensity screen)              72 x 72 px 
xhdpi (320 dpi) (Extra-high density screen)     96 x 96 px
```